# C#: How to fix System.TypeInitializationException when accessing an instance of a class via a singleton class?

Tags: c#, winforms, class, singleton

Exception detail:
[image]I am trying to retrieve an instance of a form from a singleton class but I am getting System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'form.Single' threw an exception.'

Singleton class is shown below.

```
class Single
{
    public Form1 Form { get; private set; }
    public Menu MenuForm { get; private set; }
    public RandomFacts RandomFactsForm { get; private set; }
    public QuizMenu QuizMenuForm { get; private set; }
    public AskHowManyQuestions AskHowManyQuestionsForm { get; private set; }

    private static readonly Form1 _form1 = new Form1();
    private static readonly Menu _menu = new Menu();
    private static readonly RandomFacts _randomFacts = new RandomFacts();
    private static readonly QuizMenu _quizMenu = new QuizMenu();
    private static readonly AskHowManyQuestions _askHowManyQuestions = new AskHowManyQuestions();

    private static readonly Single _single = new Single();

    private Single()
    {
        Form = _form1;
        MenuForm = _menu;
        RandomFactsForm = _randomFacts;
        QuizMenuForm = _quizMenu;
        AskHowManyQuestionsForm = _askHowManyQuestions;
    }

    public static Single GetSingle()
    {
        return _single;
    }
```

Code inside Form1 class that throws the TypeInitializationException that is meant to retrieve the instance of the class:

```
var MenuForm = Single.GetSingle().MenuForm;
```

How do I stop this exception from being thrown? Thanks for reading.

Comment: The code you posted does not exhibit the problem you're describing. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I can see from the included screenshot that there's an inner exception--an `ArgumentException` with message "Parameter is not valid." Its details should tell you where the actual problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The exception means that something in your static initialization is throwing an exception. The difficulty is that your class creates 5 objects in static initializers, and you have no idea which one is throwing the exception.

I would get rid of the singleton pattern for now and just instance methods until you figure out what the problem is. Then, if you *need* a singleton pattern (it's not clear why you do at this point), and if the problem could happen in the wild, then add exception handling and/or logging to be able to identify the problem at runtime.

As a side note, I would NOT call your class `Single`. There is already a framework class called `Single` that casual observers (like me) would be confused by. I would call it something more descriptive (`SingletonFormManager` or something like that).